# querydsl over collections In clause

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm using querydsl over collections.
I'm trying to get all the elements that are contained in another list.

```
public class Parent {
   private List<Child>;
}

public class Child {
   private String key;
   private String value;
}
```

Due a concrete list of Child objects (`List<Child> lovedChilds`), for each parent I need to select those childs are included in `lovedChilds`.

```
List<Parent> parents = ...;
for (Parent parent in parents)
{
    select
       from (child, parent.childs)
       where lovedChilds contains a lovedChild 
         where child.getKey.equals(lovedChild.getKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an **n:m relation** you should have a cross table somewhere.
I asume it to be `parent2child` with the columns `parent` and `child` (foreign keys to the corresponding ID columns).

Simply perform a join:

```
select * from parent join parent2child join child where child.key in lovedChildren
```

If you want to get the parent objects only once, you can add a `group by` or a `distinct`.